# Opening csv of specific sequences: NAs come out of nowhere?

Tags: r, csv

I feel like this is a relatively straightforward question, and I feel I'm close but I'm not passing edge-case testing. I have a directory of CSVs and instead of reading all of them, I only want some of them. The files are in a format like 001.csv, 002.csv,...,099.csv, 100.csv, 101.csv, etc which should help to explain my `if()` logic in the loop.  For example, to get all files, I'd do something like:

```
id = 1:1000
setwd("D:/")
filenames = as.character(NULL)
for (i in id){

  if(i < 10){
    i <- paste("00",i,sep="")
  }
  else if(i < 100){
    i <- paste("0",i,sep="")
  }

  filenames[[i]] <- paste(i,".csv", sep="")

}

y <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

The above code works fine for `id=1:1000`, for `id=1:10`, `id=20:70` but as soon as I pass it `id=99:100` or any sequence involving numbers starting at over 100, it introduces a lot of NAs.

Example output below for `id=98:99`

```
> filenames
      098       099 
"098.csv" "099.csv"
```

Example output below for `id=99:100`

```
> filenames
      099                                                                                 
"099.csv"        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 

"100.csv"
```

I feel like I'm missing some catch statement in my `if()` logic. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the loop for creating the `filenames`

```
 filenames <- sprintf('%03d.csv', 1:1000)
 y <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

@akrun has given you a much better way of solving your task. But in terms of the actual issue with your code, the problem is that for i < 100 you subset by a character vector (implicitly converted using `paste`) while for i >= 100 you subset by an integer. When you use `id = 99:100` this translates to:

```
filenames <- character(0)
filenames["099"] <- "099.csv" # length(filenames) == 1L
filenames[100] <- "100.csv" # length(filenames) == 100L, with all(filenames[2:99] == NA)
```

Assigning to a named member of a vector that doesn't yet exist will create a new member at position `length(vector) + 1` whereas assigning to a numbered position that is > `length(vector)` will also fill in every intervening position with NA.

Comment: I can't reproduce the NAs' you are talking about.  The `names` attributes were limited to 1:99, but after that I don't get the names, still there is no NAs

Comment: @akrun your code is fine. The OP's code produces NAs when id includes numbers >= 100 but not every number <100. For example, if `id == c(1:98, 100)` filenames will be a vector length 100 with an NA in the 99th position. Did you try my example?

Comment: @akrun the OP's code as listed works fine because id is assigned to be 1:1000. The issue comes when id is e.g. 99:100 **at the time the for loop is run**

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, although less efficient than @akrun's solution, is with the following function:

```
merged <- function(id = 1:332) {
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:length(id)){
    add <- read.csv(sprintf('%03d.csv', id[i]))
    df <- rbind(df,add)
  }
  df
}
```

Now, you can merge the files with:

```
dat <- merged(99:100)
```

Furthermore, you can assign columnnames by inserting the following line in the function just before the last line with `df`:

```
colnames(df) <- c(..specify the colnames in here..)
```

Comment: It should be noted that @akrun's solution is more efficient since it calls rbind just once rather than 332 times. I would also avoid assigning to the global environment within a function. It would be better to replace the last line of the function with `df` and then use `dat <- merged(99:100)`.

Comment: @NickK I know it's less efficient (now also reflected in my answer). But why a downvote for a solution that works?

Comment: In general, I feel that it's not good practice to be demonstrating coding of functions that modify the global environment unless there's a good reason to do so which there isn't here - the assignment should be done outside of the function not within it. However, I agree that your solution works and the downvote was perhaps unfair so have removed it. My original reason was to help push @akrun's to the top, but I should of course have let others upvote his rather than downvote yours.

Comment: @NickK thanx for the comments & explanation, I've updated my answer (and upvoted @ akrun's answer, as it is the most efficient one)